# Implementing Process Safety in Python using multiprocessing

Tags: python, queue, locking, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to write a basic python script using the multiprocessing library. The goal is to have a while loop which runs forever until a keyboard interrupt. During the while loop it will request a command which will be entered. Depending on this command it will create a process which runs a specific function and then store this in a process queue. At the end of each while loop, it will grab the first queue off the process queue and run it. I would like thread-safety in that only one process will run but am having trouble figuring out how to implement this using the lock utility provided in multiprocessing. I've attached my code below, any help is greatly appreciated. Currently, it is safe in that one process will run but if the queue increases over 1 it won't run at all.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np

l = multiprocessing.Lock()
semaphore = 0
processHold = 0

def proc1():
    global l
    global semaphore
    global processHold
    matrix_inverse()
    print 'proc1 done'
    return

def proc2():
    global l
    global semaphore
    global processHold
    print 'proc2 done'
    return

def matrix_inverse():
    global l
    global semaphore
    global processHold
    M = np.random.rand(2500,2500)
    Minv = np.linalg.inv(M)

def main():
    global l
    global semaphore
    global processHold
    processQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    while(True):
        cmd = raw_input('Enter proc1 or proc2')
        if cmd == 'proc1':
            name = 'myProc1'
            processQueue.put(name)
        elif cmd =='proc2':
            name = 'myProc2'
            processQueue.put(name)
        else:
            print 'invalid command'
        if processHold==1:
            print 'enter here'
            if p.is_alive==True:
                processHold==1
                print 'process is still alive, set processHold'
            processHold==0
            print 'stuck in processHold'
            print 'processhold '+str(processHold)
        print 'qsize '+str(processQueue.qsize())
        if (processQueue.qsize()>0)&(processHold==0):
            if semaphore>0:
                l.release()
                semaphore=semaphore-1
                print 'stuck in semaphore'
                print 'semaphore '+str(semaphore)
            currentProcess = processQueue.get()
            if currentProcess=='myProc1':
                l.acquire(block=True, timeout=None)
                semaphore=semaphore+1
                p = Process(name=currentProcess,target=proc1)
                processHold=processHold+1
                print 'stuck in myProc1'
            elif currentProcess=='myProc2':
                l.acquire(block=True, timeout=None)
                semaphore=semaphore+1
                p = Process(name=currentProcess,target=proc2)
                processHold=processHold+1
                print 'stuck in myProc2'

            p.start()
        elif (processQueue.qsize()>0)&(processHold==1):
            print 'Current process running: '+str(currentProcess)+' with '+str(processQueue.qsize())+' processes waiting'
        else:
            print 'no current processes'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you want only one process to run at at time?  You realise processes are separate from eachother right? So they can run at the same time...

Comment: I would like to have a few global variables in my process and only want it to be modified by one program at a time. I would like to treat each process as one big critical section.

Comment: Sorry, also what do you mean separate from each other? Are you saying each new process spawned will operate in a different thread?

Comment: Umm, well, do some reading on the difference between a process and a thread.  Basically you can have multiple threads in any one process.

But if you want to have global variables, shared, then yes, you need to use threads I guess.

But if you don't need to do that, then use multiprocessing as opposed to multithreading and each process will operate independently, so no need for locks etc.